# Aurelia HTTP client not sending headers

Tags: get, aurelia

I'm trying to send a simple HTTP GET request to an API. The API validates the request by looking at the `x-access-token` header.

However, even though I set the headers on the HTTP client, the header values are not sent.

Here's my DAL

```
import {HttpClient} from 'aurelia-http-client';

export class BarChartDAL {

  constructor() {
    this.token = '';
  }

  getBarchartData() {
    console.log('this.token: ', this.token);
    var client = new HttpClient()
      .configure(config => {
        config.withHeader('x-access-token', this.token);
        config.withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      });

    return client.get('http://127.0.0.1:1337/colors')
      .then(data => {
        console.log('got datapoints from server: ', data.response);
        return (JSON.parse(data.response));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('failed to get a response');
        return false;
      });
  }

  setToken(token) {
    this.token = token;
  }
}
```

However, on the server, the header of the request just show

```
request.headers { host: '127.0.0.1:1337',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'access-control-request-method': 'GET',
  origin: 'http://localhost:9000',
  'user-agent': '',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'content-type, x-access-token',
  accept: '*/*',
  referer: 'http://localhost:9000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, sdch, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8' 
}
```

As you can see, there's no `x-access-token header`

I've got a working example [here](https://github.com/gitKearney/aurelia-auth-demo), well working in the sense that it'll send an HTTP GET, and, if I remove authentication on the server, data will come back to the client.